how to get a successful auth-callback message from trpc.authCallback.useQuery()? (react query v5 2024)
I've been trying to build a chatPDF project from Josh Tried Coding - on youtube
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztBJqzBU5kc&t=7558s). the problem for me starts at 2:06:00 when his useQuery() function in the page.tsx document does not work for me as it says No overload matches this call.
Then I researched and found that as per the latest react query version (v5), onSuccess and onError are deprecated.
Then I read another stackoverflow post where someone recommended to use isSuccess and isError so I did that.
But I still didn't get a successful authcallback when I Inspect Element on localhost:3000/auth-callback. (refer images below)
[here is the workaround code that i implemented]
[here is the error message on Inspect Element]
another picture of the error i received
error message received
[this is what i expected to see on my network window]
[this is the code that i found in the tutorial, which was using v4 of react query]
please guide me as to what i have to do. thanks...

please prefer code snippets instead of images. it will be a lot easier to help out then.

sorry :) i am new to stack overflow and this is my first post. i will do better next time.

You seem to have two issues, one regarding 401 Unauthorized from the server, and one regarding removal of onSuccess/onError callbacks.
The onSuccess/onError callbacks control application behavior after you have received a response from the server and they depend on this response. onSuccess/onError does not affect the response.
As seen in the images you receive 401 Unauthorized and not 200 OK as desired. What is the root cause for this is impossible to say from the provided code.
On the other hand, your solution to the removal of onSuccess/onError looks good, except you should probably wrap them in useEffect.
Here is a blog post explaining the new API in TanStack Query v5. https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose

i had your same issue.
Assuming your kinde authentication is integrated into your local dev environment, you need to sign in/create account in "http://localhost:3000/" . Then once your email is displayed, you know you are signed in.
After that, go to "http://localhost:3000/dashboard" and your email will pop up.
If you are not signed in, then you will get a 403 error message I believe.
